# How to statistically compare the frequencies of two different words in a single corpus

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, natural-language, proportion, text-mining

Suppose I have a large corpus of text data and I would like to compare the frequencies of words $w_1$ and $w_2$. How would I go about testing whether or not their respective frequencies, $f_1$ and $f_2$ differ significantly?

At first glance, you'd think you'd be able to apply a simple proportion test to compare the two frequencies, but in practice, I'm not sure if that would be acceptable as the proportion test commonly assumes two-*independent* samples. Unfortunately, in this case, there is just one sample and so the two frequencies are not technically independent (at least as far as I understand).

Comment: Interesting question. Thinking out loud: think about what is your population here and what is the random variable in this population. My understanding is that set of all possible words is your sample space. Now your text is sequence of draws from this space but not each word has same probability of being drawn. Idea is to check whether the probabilities for two such words is same or not. Further, their frequencies in a sample should follow binomial distribution. For large enough sample, normality can be assumed and usual tests should be applicable. Sounds right?

Comment: @Dayne So in this problem, there are two non-independent random variables, the frequency (or proportion) of $w_1$ and that of $w_2$. Here, we could imagine that the population could be all books in existence and my corpus would be a random sample of books (not actually my exact problem). And I don't think the binomial distribution would apply here as there are words other than $w_1$ and $w_2$ that can occur. What makes these two variables non-independent, is that if one word occurs then the other cannot - which makes them dependent.

Comment: Yes sorry...it should be multinomial distribution. The point about non-independence argument is a bit unclear. In binomial/multinomial also failure/success cannot happen simultaneously...they are all exclusive. What I meant was the text can be thought of as a sequence of words and each word is drawn independently of each other (which obv is not a good assumption if we talk about only meaningful sentences). The extent to which you can make this assumption depends on exact purpose of your exercise.